# Does Joomla support DELETE http requests

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

Does Joomla have a method or object that I can use to get the DELETE request parameters from? I am not seeing it anywhere. This is for Joomla 3.0

Comment: Apart from using DELETE in the case of RESTful web servives, what exactly do you want to do with DELETE?

Comment: Just DELETE and PUT. But it looks like these Request types are not supported the reason I want to use them is that they help make a much cleaner API URL structure. You can reuse URL's and just check for the Request method. This is the preferred way to structure the API urls other frameworks support the structure like ZF2.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this request types are working. Check this out:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
echo "Method is: " . $jinput->getMethod();
$x = $jinput->get('x');
var_dump($x);
```

Comment: this kinda works but is not a good solution. Joomla just doesn't have a way to route proper API requests. I am actually working on extending the controller class on GitHub so that I can do this.

Comment: Maybe you can show an example in PHP of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Error: 404 - Not found

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about DELETE, but for PUT check this out: PHP: [PUT method support](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php).

There's Joomla [Web Services Working Group](http://docs.joomla.org/Web_Services_Working_Group) that recently published [Joomla CMS Web Service API Implementation](http://docs.joomla.org/Web_Services_Working_Group).

Although Web Service API is not part of current Joomla distribution yet, this is recommended way to design your REST API.